# How to change Tab Title Name by dynamically clicking a button?

Tags: android, tabs, fragment, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using **Collapsed ToolBar**  with 2 TabFragment (Login,SignUp) in my app.

LogIn fragment has both the functionality of LogIn & Forgot Password.

**LOGIN FRAGMENT**

***LOGIN***   --->***TAB NAME - LOGIN***

Email   --> EditText

Username   --> EditText

LogIn Button  --> Button

Already Have an Account?  --> TextView    --> If this textview click, Forgot Password view is set to visible &  this Login View has to be invisible.

***FORGOT PASSWORD***   ---> ***Tab Title Name need to change as Forgot Password***

How to change this tab title name while clicking button?

Another doubt is I need this tab to be swipped in Left & Right.

Layout Code:
activity_tab.xml:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    style="@style/Layout_mm"
    android:background="@color/background_2"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        style="@style/Layout_mm"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            style="@style/Layout_mw"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <RelativeLayout
                style="@style/Layout_mw"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/green_slide"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/eighty_dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/eighty_dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/login_logo" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/forty_dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            style="@style/Layout_mm"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**loginfragment.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/Layout_mm"
    android:background="@color/background_2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardlist_item"
        style="@style/Layout_mw"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/twelve_dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fifty_dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/three_dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/loginLayout"
            style="@style/Layout_mw"
            android:background="@color/background_2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/fifteen_dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty_dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty_dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/four_dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color_1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty_dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/twenty_dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty_dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/four_dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color_1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtForgot"
                style="@style/Layout_mw"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Forgot Password?"
                android:textColor="@color/hint_forgot" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/butGo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty_dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/twenty_dp"
                android:background="@drawable/orange_curved"
                android:elevation="@dimen/ten_dp"
                android:text="GO"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ForgotLayout"
            style="@style/Layout_mw"
            android:background="@color/background_2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/fifteen_dp">

            <TextView
                style="@style/Layout_ww"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Forgot Password"
                android:textColor="@color/hint_forgot" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty_dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextEmailF"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty_dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/four_dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color_1" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/forgotBut"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty_dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/thirty_dp"
                android:background="@drawable/orange_curved"
                android:elevation="@dimen/ten_dp"
                android:text="RESET PASSWORD"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/alreadyAccount"
                style="@style/Layout_ww"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Already Have an Account?"
                android:textColor="@color/hint_forgot" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which library or view you are using for tabs?

Comment: And please do add the relevant code

Comment: Added codes.Please check it.

Comment: I've added my answer in the Answer's or solution's section below. Please do have a look.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using **android.support.design.widget.TabLayout**

Get your selected Tab position and set the title-

```
 TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(position);
 tab.setText("title");
```

hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the TabLayout and ViewPager in your project, you can change the tab title by help of TabLayout.

Firstly, you need to retrieve the correct tab from your TabLayout. For this you need getTabAt() method of the TabLayout class. This method will give you the Tab at the position you specify in the method's arguments. You'll receive TabLayout.Tab from the method.

Now, you just need to change the title of this TabLayout.Tab object by help of the setText() method of the TabLayout.Tab object.

For more info, go through the following links:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html